# Automatic reboot of server for no reason

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, reboot

My server has restarted and I can't find a reason for this..
Installed on kvm virtualizor server.
I checked the logs but didn't see the reason for the restart.

last +x reboot

```
[root@localhost ~]# last +x reboot
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.27.2. Thu Sep 12 10:55 - 11:26  (00:31)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.27.2. Thu Sep 12 10:26 - 11:26  (00:59)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Sep 12 06:35 - 11:26  (04:51)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Sep 12 06:14 - 11:26  (05:11)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Sep 12 03:32 - 11:26  (07:53)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Sep 12 01:26 - 11:26  (10:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Sep 12 01:06 - 11:26  (10:20)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Sep 12 00:49 - 11:26  (10:36)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Wed Sep 11 17:48 - 11:26  (17:38)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Wed Sep 11 14:40 - 11:26  (20:45)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Wed Sep 11 09:34 - 11:26 (1+01:52)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 17:57 - 11:26 (2+17:29)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 16:49 - 11:26 (2+18:37)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 14:36 - 11:26 (2+20:49)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 14:13 - 11:26 (2+21:12)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 13:34 - 11:26 (2+21:51)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 12:15 - 11:26 (2+23:11)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 10:17 - 11:26 (3+01:09)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 04:07 - 11:26 (3+07:18)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 02:53 - 11:26 (3+08:32)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 02:23 - 11:26 (3+09:02)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 01:45 - 11:26 (3+09:40)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 01:25 - 11:26 (3+10:01)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Sep  9 00:34 - 11:26 (3+10:52)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Aug 26 23:08 - 11:26 (16+12:17)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Sun Aug 25 09:41 - 11:26 (18+01:44)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Jul 25 21:47 - 11:26 (48+13:39)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Thu Jul 25 14:23 - 11:26 (48+21:03)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Jul 22 16:19 - 11:26 (51+19:07)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.21.3. Mon Jul 22 16:13 - 11:26 (51+19:12)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.el7.x Mon Jul 22 15:53 - 16:12  (00:19)
```

grep -B20 -A10 "Linux version" /var/log/messages

```
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xae, date = 2019-02-14
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/VG1-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG1/root rd.md.uuid=b44eee21:206396c1:2f2e93d7:0e19e420 rd.lvm.lv=VG1/swap nomodeset rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009d3ff] usable
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000033720fff] usable
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000033721000-0x0000000033721fff] ACPI NVS
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000033722000-0x0000000033722fff] reserved
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000033723000-0x000000003abb7fff] usable
Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000003abb8000-0x000000003b033fff] reserved
--
Sep 12 10:44:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 21 of user root.
Sep 12 10:45:02 localhost systemd: Started Session 22 of user root.
Sep 12 10:46:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 23 of user root.
Sep 12 10:47:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 24 of user root.
Sep 12 10:48:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 25 of user root.
Sep 12 10:48:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 26 of user root.
Sep 12 10:48:03 localhost libvirtd: 2019-09-12 06:18:03.635+0000: 3574: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1806 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Sep 12 10:48:07 localhost libvirtd: 2019-09-12 06:18:07.040+0000: 3574: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1806 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Sep 12 10:49:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 27 of user root.
Sep 12 10:50:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 28 of user root.
Sep 12 10:51:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 29 of user root.
Sep 12 10:52:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 30 of user root.
Sep 12 10:53:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 31 of user root.
Sep 12 10:54:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 32 of user root.
Sep 12 10:54:20 localhost dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 178.63.197.203 via natbr8
Sep 12 10:54:20 localhost dhcpd: DHCPACK to 178.63.197.203 (00:16:3e:22:2c:83) via natbr8
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xae, date = 2019-02-14
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/VG1-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=VG1/root rd.md.uuid=b44eee21:206396c1:2f2e93d7:0e19e420 rd.lvm.lv=VG1/swap nomodeset rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009d3ff] usable
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000033720fff] usable
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000033721000-0x0000000033721fff] ACPI NVS
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000033722000-0x0000000033722fff] reserved
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000033723000-0x000000003abb7fff] usable
Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000003abb8000-0x000000003b033fff] reserved
```

grep -iv ': starting\|kernel: .*: Power Button\|watching system buttons\|Stopped Cleaning Up\|Started Crash recovery kernel' \
  /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog /var/log/apcupsd* \
  | grep -iw 'recover[a-z]*\|power[a-z]*\|shut[a-z ]*down\|rsyslogd\|ups'

```
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V0PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V1PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V2PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [PIN] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:24 localhost kernel:  hash matches drivers/base/power/main.c:576
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:31 localhost systemd-fsck: /dev/sda2: recovering journal
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:33 localhost systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:39 localhost systemd: Started Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:14:39 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-34.el7" x-pid="3541" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V0PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V1PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V2PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:13 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [PIN] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:21 localhost systemd-fsck: /dev/sda2: recovering journal
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:22 localhost systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:27 localhost systemd: Started Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 06:35:27 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-34.el7" x-pid="3542" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 09:21:10 localhost systemd: Stopping Crash recovery kernel arming...
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 09:21:10 localhost systemd: Stopped Crash recovery kernel arming.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 09:21:28 localhost dracut: *** Including module: shutdown ***
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 09:21:50 localhost dracut: *** Including module: shutdown ***
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V0PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V1PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V2PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:42 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [PIN] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:44 localhost systemd-fsck: /dev/mapper/VG1-root: recovering journal
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:50 localhost systemd-fsck: /dev/sda2: recovering journal
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:51 localhost systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:58 localhost systemd: Started Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:26:58 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-34.el7" x-pid="3563" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:27:28 localhost dracut: *** Including module: shutdown ***
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V0PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V1PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [V2PR] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN01] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN02] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN03] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [FN04] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:16 localhost kernel: ACPI: Power Resource [PIN] (off)
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:24 localhost systemd-fsck: /dev/sda2: recovering journal
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:25 localhost systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:31 localhost rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-34.el7" x-pid="3559" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:31 localhost systemd: Started Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown.
grep: /var/log/syslog/var/log/messages:Sep 12 10:55:44 localhost dracut: *** Including module: shutdown ***
: No such file or directory
grep: /var/log/apcupsd*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: if this is vm check the host machine logs.